# C# Assign Each TxtBox a array index?

Tags: c#, loops, textbox

I'm looking for a more elegant solution than what I have here

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int[] randomArray = new int[7];

        int Min = 1;
        int Max = 60;

        Random rand = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            genBtn.Focus();
        }

        private void genBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        for (var i = 0; i < randomArray.Length; i++)
            {
                randomArray[i] = rand.Next(Min, Max); // Remember to assign random number
            }



            boxNum1.Text = randomArray[0].ToString();
            boxNum2.Text = randomArray[1].ToString();
            boxNum3.Text = randomArray[2].ToString();
            boxNum4.Text = randomArray[3].ToString();
            boxNum5.Text = randomArray[4].ToString();
            boxNum6.Text = randomArray[5].ToString();
            boxNum7.Text = randomArray[6].ToString();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I hate the boxNum1.Text - randomArray[0].ToString(); but it's the only way I can figure doing it, is there a more obvious solution I'm not thinking off?

Comment: Couldn't you just loop over all Children of the Form? (And maybe tag the textboxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your boxes into an array, remove `randomArray`, and assign `Text` property directly:

```
private void genBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (box in new[]{boxNum1, boxNum2, boxNum3, boxNum4, boxNum5, boxNum6, boxNum7}) {
         box.Text = rand.Next(Min, Max).ToString();
    }
}
```

> I thought [of] creating a textbox array

You can create an array at the class level, rather than at the local level:

```
private readonly TextBox[] allBoxes;
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    allBoxes = new TextBox[] {
        boxNum1, boxNum2, boxNum3, boxNum4, boxNum5, boxNum6, boxNum7
    };
}
private void genBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (box in allBoxes) {
         box.Text = rand.Next(Min, Max).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @LiamVallance `boxNum1`...`boxNum7` are not assigned until after `InitializeComponents` method is run, while initializers run before `InitializeComponents`. Since the value of `boxNum...` depends on timing *within* the constructor, C# prohibits it altogether.

Comment: @LiamVallance Correct, `Control` is a subclass of `Object`, and `TextBox` is a subclass of `Control`, so everything can be used as an `Object`.